# How to upload PM order confirmation : actual data using BAPI in SAP

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi

How to upload PM order confirmation actual data and post goods movement using BAPI in SAP ?

I tried to use a lot of BAPI but it didn't work like this:
MAP2E_RIWOL_TO_ALM_ORDER_OLIST , BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN , BAPI_PRODORDCONF_GET_TT_PROP

These are the steps that the user follows in entering the data using (T-Code IW41 ) ,
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

I'm in need an appropriate BAPI for these steps.

Answer (score 1):

To post Time confirmations use `'BAPI_ALM_CONF_CREATE'`

To post goods movement , is a loaded question,
but if we assume a basic MM goods issue to order , use `'BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE'`
use Goods movement code of 03 and a movement type 261.
gm_code = '03'.
goodmvt_item-move_type = '261'

The Object LIST is maintained via the ORDER.
see BAPI_ALM_ORDER_MAINTAIN.
The object list is part of this function.
Example for you test program to post confirmations.

" map_timeconf example using variable names similar to afru

```
DATA: ls_timetickets TYPE bapi_alm_timeconfirmation.

ls_timetickets-orderid = i_aufnr.
ls_timetickets-operation = i_vornr.
ls_timetickets-sub_oper = i_uvorn.


IF is_timec_up-split IS NOT INITIAL.
  ls_timetickets-capa_category = '002'. "Person
  ls_timetickets-split = is_timec_up-split.
ENDIF.
ls_timetickets-fin_conf = is_timec_up-aueru.
ls_timetickets-clear_res = is_timec_up-ausor.

ls_timetickets-conf_text = is_timec_up-ltxa1.
ls_timetickets-plant     = is_timec_up-werks.
ls_timetickets-work_cntr = is_timec_up-arbpl.

ls_timetickets-act_work_2 = is_timec_up-ismnw.
ls_timetickets-un_work = is_timec_up-ismne.
ls_timetickets-rem_work = is_timec_up-ofmnw.
ls_timetickets-un_rem_wrk = is_timec_up-ofmne.
ls_timetickets-actual_dur = is_timec_up-idaur.
ls_timetickets-un_act_dur = is_timec_up-idaue.
ls_timetickets-exec_start_date = is_timec_up-isdd.
ls_timetickets-exec_start_time = is_timec_up-isdz.
ls_timetickets-exec_fin_date = is_timec_up-iedd.
ls_timetickets-exec_fin_time = is_timec_up-iedz.
ls_timetickets-pers_no = is_timec_up-pernr.

ls_timetickets-act_type = """"" <<<<< is important

ls_timetickets-calc_motive = is_timec_up-bemot.


ls_timetickets-ex_created_by = is_timec_up-ernam.
ls_timetickets-ex_created_date = is_timec_up-ersda.
ls_timetickets-dev_reason = is_timec_up-grund.

ls_timetickets-postg_date =   !!!!  sy-datum
                                  

APPEND ls_timetickets TO lt_timetickets.



CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_ALM_CONF_CREATE'
  EXPORTING
    post_wrong_entries = ' '
    testrun            = i_testrun
  IMPORTING
    return             = ls_return
  TABLES
    timetickets        = lt_timetickets
    detail_return      = lt_alm_return.


COMMIT WORK. "! You can only do 1 at a time
           " indeed you may need a new session each time.
```

Comment: +1, but why is asking how to post a goods movement a [loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question)?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work with me , I attached pictures showing the steps that the user follows in entering the data using (T-Code IW41 )  thanx for the reply.

Comment: @A-G "doesn't work with me" isn't useful feedback to give to someone who tries to help you. Imagine you developed a software and the customer would say "doesn't work for me, I won't pay" and nothing else. How would you feel about that? So please tell us: **why** doesn't it work for you? Do you get an error message? Doesn't it do everything you need?

Comment: @philipp when the goods issue involves Warehouse Mgt.  Different steps are required. Eg Transfer orders . A-G didnt state whether is was basic MM, so we assume it is.
Eg L_TO_CREATE_SINGLE

Comment: What did you try.   Im quietly confident that the  FUNCTION can be used to post time confirmations for PM Orders. Share the error messages...

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying  my response ,just want to state that's not working with me however here you go a complete explanation of the situation:
I tried this solution through se37 I using TEST SEQUENCES ,insert  BAPI_ALM_CONF_CREATE & BAPI_TRANSACTION_commit and  Sand filled in all the required fields.  I did not find the data by viewing it on se43 and they did not give me any error message , I think that the user must choose the object list and then mark the check box of 'Processing indicator'  then write function location before saving. Do you have a suitable BAPI to enter the object list.

Comment: Note, I am new in the  ABAP field , and I am not familiar with all the function of this language, and for this I resorted to stackoverflow community to help me, and thanks again for trying to helping me sort it out :)

Comment: Ive added  Object list, maint to answer.   I recommend you a test program rather that just trying Se37 test calls due to commit handling.

Comment: if your test program isnt working, then we can help with that.

Comment: @phil soady Thanks for the code but .The test program give me error message "Please Fill Functional loc. from object list"

Comment: @A-G code and error message details.   Now we are talking about something other than time conf.  Object list has nothing to do with Timeconf.   A new question is appropriate

Comment: before saying "doesn't work" always check return parameter of BAPI (bapiret2) and what is returned there after the call, it can may be very probably that you call that BAPI wrong, not the solution suggested is wrong